# Creating in java String Array contain paths when given a root folder

Tags: java, arrays, string, path, root

I have a folder (some root folder) in my computer that contains a lot of folders and files. I need to create a String Array that contain all paths (starting from the root folder) of the files (I mean only the leaves = files, not folders). How can I do this?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using standard Java SE classes and recursion you could do it this way:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File root = new File("D:\\Downloaded"); // path to root folder
        process(root);
    }

    private static void process(File path) {
        File[] subs = path.listFiles();
        if (subs != null) {
            for (File f : subs) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    process(f);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, instead of `System.out.println()` you'd probably want to put the path to some `ArrayList`.

Comment: So, shoe me how to put it in ArrayList?